# Update data extension where multiple records exist for single user

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to update an action table (action meaning they have confirmed their appointment) with a loop to look at the head of household id (HOHid) and then insert value for each appointment associated with that head of household. (Sometimes a head of household will have more than one appointment to confirm). The loop is working, but it updates with the same appointment information each time. So if John Doe has 3 appointments, and confirms all 3, instead of inserting appointment data for each, it inserts appointment data for the first one 3 times.

```
     Set @familyid = FamilyID
     Set @HOHid = HOHid

     Set @FamilyTotal = Rowcount(Lookuprows(@DELookUp,"FamilyID",@familyid))
     Set @GroupRecords = LookupOrderedRows(@DELookUp,0,"AppointmentDateTime","FamilyID",@familyid)

     If @FamilyTotal == 1 THEN
     Set @Plural = ""
     ELSE
     Set @Plural = "s"     
     ENDIF

     for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@GroupRecords) do 

Set @row = Row(@GroupRecords,@i)

Set @FamilyAppt = Field(@row,"AppointmentID")
Set @ApptSubscriberKey = Field(@row,"Subscriber Key")
Set @PatientID = Field(@row,"Subscriber Key")   

If @i == 1 THEN
    Set @FamilyFirstNames = Propercase(Field(@row,"PatientFirstName"))
    Set @FamilyApptTime = Field(@row,"AppointmentDateTime")
    Set @FamilyApptDay = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"dddd")
    Set @FamilyApptMonth = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"MMM")
    Set @FamilyApptDate = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"dd")
    Set @StartTime = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"h:mm tt")
    Set @ApptDisplay = Concat(@FamilyApptDay,", ",@FamilyApptMonth," ",@FamilyApptDate," at ",@StartTime,"")
    Set @SubjectLineDate = Concat(Format(@FamilyApptTime,"MMMM"),' ',Replace(@FamilyApptDate,"0",""),'')
    Set @ApptClinicID = Lookup(@DEClinic,"ClinicID","AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt)
    Set @FriendlyClinicName = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","FacilityName","CRMFacilityID",@ApptClinicID)

ENDIF
    SET @ActionType = "Confirm"
INSERTDE(
    "ET_Appointment_Action",
    "AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt, 
    "FamilyId",@familyid,
    "PatientID",@PatientID,
    "AppointmentDateTime",@FamilyApptTime, 
    "AppointmentClinicID",@ApptClinicID, 
    "ActionDateTime",@ActionDateTime, 
    "ActionType",@ActionType, 
    "Campaign_Name",@CampaignName, 
    "Send_id",@JobId,
    "EventDate", RequestParameter('ed')
   )    
Next
```

Comment: What's the primary key on this Data Extension?

Comment: We are not using a primary key for this DE.

Comment: My thought now is that we should use an update to the data. Thoughts on this approach?

Comment: Could you explain how the confirmation process works?  InsertDE is for emails only, and I don't quite get how someone gets one email but can confirm three times.

Comment: They can only confirm one time on the landing page, but they may be confirming three appointments. So our Landing Page will have the reminder saying "You have your appointment(s) coming up on _date_. Please confirm". That person may have more than one appointment shown. They receive a 10 day reminder, 3 day reminder, and 1 day reminder email. All of which they can confirm again.

Comment: To clarify, we are using the CTA in the email to update the data extension. The LP is only showing that the appointment has been confirmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things that may be going on here.

1) You are using `InsertDE` on a landing page, and that function is used in email only. I would suggest using [`UpsertData`](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/UpsertData.html)

```
UPSERTDATA(deName, numberOfKeyColumns, whereColumn, whereValue [...], insertColumn,InsertValue[...]
```

2) Since you are seeing the same data populated for each row, I think this section of code is throwing it off

```
If @i == 1 THEN
    Set @FamilyFirstNames = Propercase(Field(@row,"PatientFirstName"))
    Set @FamilyApptTime = Field(@row,"AppointmentDateTime")
    Set @FamilyApptDay = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"dddd")
    Set @FamilyApptMonth = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"MMM")
    Set @FamilyApptDate = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"dd")
    Set @StartTime = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"h:mm tt")
    Set @ApptDisplay = Concat(@FamilyApptDay,", ",@FamilyApptMonth," ",@FamilyApptDate," at ",@StartTime,"")
    Set @SubjectLineDate = Concat(Format(@FamilyApptTime,"MMMM"),' ',Replace(@FamilyApptDate,"0",""),'')
    Set @ApptClinicID = Lookup(@DEClinic,"ClinicID","AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt)
    Set @FriendlyClinicName = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","FacilityName","CRMFacilityID",@ApptClinicID)

ENDIF
```

That `if` statement there is grabbing only the first row's data. remove the `If @i == 1 THEN` and the `ENDIF`.

3) Finally - update the `Next` at the end to be `Next @i` so it increments your counter appropriately.

Let me know if that works!

Comment: I receive this error with your suggested update:
Invalid column name (parameter 2) passed to Field function.  No column of the specified name was found.
  Invalid Field Name: PatientID
  Function: Field(@currentRow, "PatientID")

Comment: You would need to use the columns in the data extension you are getting the data from. The code above is just an example.

Comment: Getting this error: Invalid object property name. Object Type: System.Int32 Property Name: AppointmentID

Comment: Without knowing your full data schema, its hard to know, but id guess that the data you are passing in doesn't match what the data extension is expecting.

Comment: Try setting up the loop, and printing it to the screen to validate the data rows.

Comment: The AppointmentID is a number. Is there a way to set the variable being passed as a number?

Comment: Is it possible to use an IF/ELSE statement that looks to see if the patient exists in a Data extension?

Comment: Thats built into the upsertde function

Comment: How does upsert execute the else portion?

Comment: If exists, update, else insert new.

Comment: Thanks! That is working for us, but it updates/inserts the appointment information identically each time. So if the email has 3 appointments and they confirm them (1 call to action) it updates/inserts the first appointment info instead of the info for each of the appointments.

Comment: Im not exactly sure what the issue is. Can you update the question with the current code. Might also help to see how you retrieve the data, and maybe some sample records. Hard to tell from the info i have so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16079/discussion-between-nicholas-dixon-and-kelly-j-andrews).

Comment: The data is being passed from the email to the landing page

Comment: Dont forget to mark this answered if its up and running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on landing pages you need to be using the InsertData call.  The InsertDE call is for emails only, and is handled differently (see [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/how_ampscript_update_insert_and_delete_calls_are_processed_during_sends/)).  You may also want to consider using UpsertData and put a primary key on the table, for ease of use going forward.

Comment: Can we use an upsert to lookup if there is a record that already exists within our action table?

%%[SET @ActionType = "Confirm"
UpsertDE(  "LL_Test_ET_Appointment_Action",1,  
"AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt,   
"FamilyId",@familyid,  
"PatientID",@PatientID,  
"AppointmentDateTime",@FamilyApptTime,  
"AppointmentClinicID",@ApptClinicID,  
"ActionDateTime",@ActionDateTime,    
"ActionType",@ActionType,  
"Campaign_Name",@CampaignName,   
"Send_id",@JobId,  
"EventDate", RequestParameter('ed'))  
]%%

Comment: If you have a primary key on that table, you can use UpsertData if calling from a landing page, or UpsertDE if calling from an email.

Comment: Spoke to soon. We cannot use an upsert because that event has to be updated each time it happens. If the user has already clicked and we use an upsert, the row will not update again because a record already exists.